# How to get value from map by key

Tags: c++, c++11

How I can get value from map by key? I have a vector of ints `A`, and I have a map. I want to print `M[1]`, but I don't understand how I can do it, because I've got an error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'mapped_type' (aka 'std::__1::pair<int, int>'))
    cout << M[1];
    ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
```

My code:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> A;
    map<int, pair<int,int> > M;

    FOR(i,1,maxN) {
        pair<int,int> p;

        p.first = 1;
        p.second = 2;

        M[i] = p;
    }

    FOR(i,0,t) {
        int x = A[i];
        cout << M[x] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try to get if first, and then try to print it, and see what goes wrong. Hint: it isn't the getting.

Comment: It looks like the `<<` operator was not overloaded to work with `std::pair<int, int>`

Comment: I am not sure what you have done to your for loops, but please don't use `#define` to make C++ look like other languages. You only confuse yourself and others. Is it really so difficult to write `for(int i=0; i<t; i++)`?

Comment: @ZanLynx This code I used for a programming competition. I don't use these macros in the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value type of the map is a std::pair. You need to individually print the 2 values in the pair:

```
cout<< M[x].first << "," << M[x].second << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Paani has a good answer. I thought I would post mine, which is the same idea but slightly different.

Instead of printing the values from the pair you can create an ostream function to print any pair.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<class T, class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const std::pair<T, U> &p) {
    os << '{' << p.first << ',' << p.second << '}';
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::pair<int, int> p(7, 11);
    std::pair<std::string, double> q("My Double", 37.02);

    std::cout << p << std::endl;
    std::cout << q << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```